# How do I ensure a certain amount of numbers are typed in?

Tags: c

I have to ensure that 10 digits are typed in, so let's say if the amount of numbers typed is less than or more than 10, it will end the process. How can I do that?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
  int accnum;

printf("Welcome to Excellent Utility Supplies utility billing program. Fill in the information below to find out the required bill to pay. Thank you\n\n");

printf("Enter Tenant ID (10 digit number):");
scanf("%d",&accnum);

return 0;
}
```

Comment: [Don't post images of code](http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode), copy-paste the code *as text* into the actual question instead. Also please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Lastly please learn how to *[edit]* your questions to improve them.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to achieve this is by finding if the number typed in is between 1000000000 and 9999999999. If the number typed in is not within the range of those two then it must have less or more digits.

Comment: Corner case: leading zeros.

Comment: true, my answer will work only if the number is of type int. Otherwise you can just check the length of the string

Comment: Actually it wouldn't work for int on most compilers because it'd overflow a 32-bit number.

Comment: so, `0123` is not an int?

Comment: yes it is, but the trailing 0 won't be "saved" if the variable is of type int will it? And yes, type long would be better, then type int

Comment: He means, `0000123456` *may* be a valid *"tenant ID"*. Using integer (or any numeric types) may not be the best option

Answer (score 0):

Place the read digits into a character array checking that they are a digit. e.g.

```
char buf[11];

/* more digits to read & able to read character & that character is a digit */
for (int i = 0; i < 10 && scanf("%c", &buf[i]) == 1 && isdigit(buf[i]); ++i) { 
}

if (i != 10) {
  /* Error */
}    
buf[i] = 0; // Make it a string, Easier to handle later
```

Comment: hi, can u explain this? I'm very new to c program and I don't really understand what some of this actually does. Is there a simpler way to do it?

Comment: The comment above the `for` loop explains the loop. Look up `scanf` etc.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main()
{
    int accnum;

    printf("Welcome to Excellent Utility Supplies utility billing program. Fill in the information below to find out the required bill to pay. Thank you\n\n");

do
{
     printf("Enter Tenant ID (10 digit number):");
     scanf("%d",&accnum);
}while ((floor (log10 (abs (accnum))) + 1)!=10);

return 0;

}
```